# Is it possible to set *ngIf on host element?

Tags: typescript, angular

I want to run `ngAfterViewInit()` every time local variable is changed. I thought about using *ngIf to trigger this function, however I don't know how to set it from component itself. `HostBinding` needless to say, doesn't work.

Here is simplified plunk of what I am trying to achieve: http://plnkr.co/edit/tflsWzsRDVNeMPjmTokF?p=preview

EDIT: My previous explanation was a little bit misleading. `*ngIf` is essential, because I don't want to display component at all if its local variable is `false`. However if it is `true`, I want to pass width and height of div inside this component to service.

Comment: Why would you want to run `ngAfterViewInit()` every time a local variable is changed. Seems somehow pointless.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The whole point is to pass width and height properties of the box to the service and I can do it onlly after view is created.

Comment: Calling `ngAfterViewInit()` doesn't ensure the view is actually already created. Only after **Angular** called `ngAfterViewInit()` you can be sure the view was initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the variable to a getter/setter and call `ngAfterViewInit()` or any other method every time the setter is called (and the new value is different from the old one)?

```
  private _show: boolean = false;

  get show():Boolean {
    return this._show;
  }
  set show(newVal:Boolean) {
    if(newVal != this._show) {
      this._show = newVal;  
      ngAfterViewInit();;
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
```